# ¿Cómo puedo redirigir salida a un fichero pero mostrar también en terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redirección

Quiero que al hacer un `echo`, a parte de sacarlo en el fichero al que he redirigido mediante `>>` también lo muestre por pantalla, sin copiar el código quitándole el `>>`.

Es decir, no quiero tener que hacer:

```
echo "hola"
echo "hola" >> fichero
```

Sino un solo comando que haga ambas cosas.

¿Cómo se puede hacer?

Comment: Saludos, es mejor si agregas tu código ó lo que has intentado para poder darte una mejor respuesta...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suponiendo que actualmente tienes algo así como:

```
echo "hola" >> fichero.log
```

La clave está en utilizar `tee`:

```
echo "hola" | tee -a fichero.log
```

Con este comando:

- `echo "hola"` muestra por pantalla
- `tee -a fichero.log` recoge el contenido de `echo` y lo añade (ojo con el `-a`) al fichero "fichero.log".

Comment: Un buen truco de `bash`, según estuve leyendo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3403786/6836377,  es hacer `exec > >(tee -i fichero.log)`, para que la salida estándar se redirija a un fichero.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho interesante, no conocía el truco. La verdad es que se pueden hacer virguerías con las redirecciones. En Bash FAQ hay [un artículo buenísimo al respecto](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/047), de nivel cada vez más avanzado.

Comment: La verdad que yo tampoco lo conocía.

Answer (score 0):

Sin duda yo preferiría usar lo que escribe @fedorqui por las múltiples opciones que tiene `tee` sin embargo hay otra opción más sencilla (más no simple ni menos rebuscada) y rudimentaria que se me ocurre **pero sólo para zsh**.

```
$ echo amiguillo pillo > /proc/$$/fd/1 >> fichero
amiguillo pillo 
$ echo amigocho ocho > $(tty) >> fichero
amigocho ocho
$ cat fichero
amiguillo pillo 
amigocho ocho
```

Donde `/proc/$$/fd/1` es un enlace simbólico a la interfaz que hace referencia al archivo de tipo caracter asociado con el entorno de salida de texto de la terminal.

Algo semejante con el comando `tty` que sólo imprime el nombre del archivo de la terminal conectada al *stdout*.